# Select random nonrepeated numbers from an array

Tags: python

I want to select non-repeated random numbers from a np array or range for only one times(for example during a for loop)

I need a python function to do this operation.

Comment: Use  `random.sample()`  https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#functions-for-sequences

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to do is very simple. You can create a list of such integers using `range` and then use `sample` to request random values without replacement:

```
from random import sample

# Choose 50 random values from 0 to 99
values = sample(range(100), k = 50)

# Your execution loop
for i in range(50):
    print(values[i])
```

Note that it's important to sample ahead of time because `sample` doesn't modify the list of values sent to it, so successive calls won't guarantee non-replacement.

If you really want to create a function you can call, you can use generators to make it work:

```
# Function that creates a generator that will yield sampled values one at a time
def create_non_replacement_sample(inputs, k):
    values = sample(inputs, k)
    def inner():
        for v in values:
            yield v
    return inner

# Create the generator to sample 50 values between 0 and 99
sampler = create_non_replacement_sample(range(100), 50)

# Execution loop
for i in range(50):
    
    # Get a random value without replacement
    value = next(sampler())

    # Print the value
    print(value)
```

This works by generating the values ahead of time, and returning a function that yields them back one-by-one. Then, within the execution loop you can call `next` to get a single random value from the result set. Note, here, that each call to `next` actually increments to the next value in the list so you should only call `next` when you want a new value.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
np.random.choice(arr)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.